# Detect plugin rollback

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Pretty simple question, but I can't find anything about it..
I have a plugin in Dynamics CRM 2013 that listens to the create and update events of an account. Depending on some business rules, some info about this account is written to an external webservice.
However, sometimes a create or update action can be rolled back from outside the scope of your plugin (for example a third party plugin), so the account won't be created or updated. The crm plugin model handles this nicely by rolling back every SDK call made in this transaction. But as I've have written some info to an **external** service I need to know when a rollback occured so that I can rollback the external operation manually.

Is there any way to detect a rollback in the plugin execution pipeline and execute some custom code? Alternative solutions are welcome too.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trigger that can be subscribed to when the plugin rolls back, but you can determine when it happens after the fact.

1. Define a new Entity (Call it "Transaction Tracker" or whatever makes sense).  Define these attributes for the entity

   - OptionSet Attribute (Call it "RollbackAction", or again, whatever makes sense).
   - A Text Attribute that'll serve as a Data Field.
2. Define a new workflow that get's kicked off when a "TransactionTracker" get's created

   - Have it's first step be a Wait Condition that is defined as a process Timeout that waits for 1 minute.
   - Have it's next step be a Custom Workflow Activity that uses the Rollback action to determine how to parse the Text Attribute, to determine if the entity has been rolled back (If it's a Create, does it exist?  If it's an update, is the entities Modified On date >= the Transaction Tracker's Date?
   - If it has been rolled back perform whatever action is nessacary, if it hasn't been rolled back, exit the workflow (Or optionally delete the TransactionTracker Entity)
3. Within your plugin, before making the external call, create an OrganizationServiceProxy (since you are creating it and not using the existing one, it will be created outside the transaction and therefore, will not get cleaned up).
4. Create a "TransactionTracker" entity with the out of transaction service, populating that attributes as necessary.

You may need to tweak the timeout, but besides that, it should work fine.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work for a simple thing though, an extra plugin stage would be a nice feature for this..
I'm guessing you could do this easily with the now deprecated stage 50 post operation. As it happens outside the transaction I guess it would never trigger if the transaction failed. Any idea why this stage was removed?

Comment: @ArneDeruwe it does seem like a lot of work.  I'm not sure the 5th stage of the plugin would help.  If the transaction gets rolled back, it wouldn't execute at all, just like when the second stage fails, the forth never gets executed.

Comment: @ArneDeruwe, it may be less work to have your external system call back in a few minutes later, just to check if the transaction actually got rolled back.

Comment: That's just it, I want it to never execute. If the account isn't created i don't want to write anything to the webservice. Good point about the call back though, I could abandon the plugin approach and poll CRM from my external system. Thx again for the help!

Comment: @ArneDeruwe if you only want it to execute if the entity gets created, It should be as simple as creating a workflow on the create of the entity that performs the external call.

Comment: Ok, so a workflow is triggered after the create/update process is complete? In that way, a failed creation would never trigger the workflow? Probably a noob question, but I have never used workflows :/

Comment: @ArneDeruwe you trigger the workflow within the plugin, but you use a new OrganizationService, so it is outside of the database transaction.  You'd want a workflow (they're async) so you could have it wait some time to check to see if the transaction was successful.